# sql server table contains special foreign characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I realized after populating the table that it contains special encoding for foreign characters. I changed it to nvarchar but how do update the records already in the table since I still see it in the table. for example

BÃ¶rsenblatt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already inserted the foreign characters into a single-byte character field (varchar, text) and changed the field to nvarchar, there is no way to retrieve the foreign characters in the existing records, unfortunately you will need to update or delete and reinsert from the original data source.